# ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "Invalid Date" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Tags: angular, date, pipe, transform

I am trying to format a date with time too but this throw an error.
The way as I am sending the request is:

```
created = this.datePipe.transform(dateCreated, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm');
```

I need the time because I am consume a service which needs this parameter with time to filter exactly the data.

The next image is the error:

[image]

Comment: It seems like `dateCreated` is not a valid date ... what is `dateCreated`? Where do you get it from?

Comment: Show more code. When you are trying to set the `dateCreated`?

Comment: I get it from a control date for angular. The data for this variable is Thu Jul 26 2018 15:30:00 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Colombia). That is the date that is trying to format

Comment: var created: string = value['startDate'].toString();
      created = created.substring(0, created.indexOf(' GMT'));
      let dateCreated = new Date(created);
      console.log(dateCreated);
      created = this.datePipe.transform(dateCreated, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm');

Comment: I do not see any issue with your code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datepipe-amit?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: what if dateCreated is 
`let dateCreated = "2021-06-29 18:24:48.000000"
<p title ="{{dateCreated | date}}">{{dateCreated | date}}</p>`

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue when trying to pass a string that was in MySQL datetime format to the transform function.

Borrowing from Jai Kumaresh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51618832/error-error-invalidpipeargument-unable-to-convert-invalid-date-into-a-date/55514672#55514672), I was able to fix this issue by first converting the MySQL datetime string into an ISO-recognized format by doing the following:

```
dateCreated = dateCreated.replace(' ', 'T');
created = this.datePipe.transform(dateCreated, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm');
```

Until I did this, Safari gave me this error, although Chrome and Firefox worked.  With this fix the issue was resolved in each of these browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Only accept date formats

```
Year:
      YYYY (eg 1997)
   Year and month:
      YYYY-MM (eg 1997-07)
   Complete date:
      YYYY-MM-DD (eg 1997-07-16)
   Complete date plus hours and minutes:
      YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00)
   Complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds:
      YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)
   Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a
second
      YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
```

[Ref by](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21716#issuecomment-360084199)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace all of your "/" in your date to "-":

```
dateCreated = formatDate(`${dateCreated}`.replaceFunction('/','-'),'full','es-CO');
```

That error is generated for the way that dates works in angular, because it cannot parse the dates that contains slashes, without a custom parser.

Or you can define a custom parser anyway, using date-fns or something like that.

Pdta: I am not going into details of a replace functions, it is not the scope of the answer here, so it doesn't matter how would you replace the date string.

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution is to use the moment library gives a better possibility of handling dates and allows the conversions that you request without error with the pipe of the template

```js
StackMoment!:string
  stacktConvert!:string;
  stack!:string;
  stackDateString!:string;
  stackDate!:Date;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getTime();
 }

  getTime(){
  // //import * as moment from 'moment';
  // para convertir usar moment permite pipe en el templete sin error de los datos requeridos
  // stacktConvert:{{stacktConvert |date:'shortTime'}}muestra stacktConvert:5:30 PM
  this.stack=' Thu Jul 26 2018 15:30:00 GMT-0500 ';
  this.StackMoment=new Date(this.stack).toISOString();
  console.log('StackMoment',this.StackMoment)
  this.stacktConvert=moment( this.StackMoment).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm")
console.log('stacktConvert',this.stacktConvert)
}
```

```html
stacktConvert:{{stacktConvert |date:'shortTime'}}
```

HTML

```html
stacktConvert:{{stacktConvert |date:'shortTime'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

just do this in your query Convert(varchar,dateCreated,101)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).