# How to convert Timestamp like "2021-07-18T9:33:58.000Z" to 18th July(for date) or 9:33 am(for time) in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to convert Timestamp like "2021-07-18T9:33:58.000Z" to 18th July(for date) or 9:33 am(for time) in angular 11?
Currently I am doing

```
    const myDate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(timestamp,'shortTime' );
```

But it throws Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "2021-07-18T9:33:58.000Z" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "Invalid Date" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51618832/error-error-invalidpipeargument-unable-to-convert-invalid-date-into-a-date)

Comment: No it still shows the same error @JSON Derulo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the value of date string. Javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor is treating your string representation, which is 2021-07-18T9:33:58.000Z, as *Invalid Date**..

```
new Date('2021-07-18T9:33:58.000Z');
Invalid Date
```

However, if you convert the string representation of the date value to **2021-07-18T09:33:58.000Z** (please mind the 2-digit '09' of hours), then the date construction will be Ok, and then the DatePipe should work.

```
new Date('2021-07-18T09:33:58.000Z');
Sun Jul 18 2021 15:03:58 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```